# Applying topological definition of continuity to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

I am trying to show that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
  $$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    \frac{1}{x}, \, x > 0 \\ 0, \, x \leq 0 \end{array} \right. $$
is not continuous by using the topological definition of continuity and the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (induced by the Euclidean metric). Here is my work.

> Let $(-1,1)$ be an interval on the $y$ axis. Then
>   $$ f^{-1}\left((-1,1)\right) = \{0\} \cup [1,\infty) $$ This set is not
>   open on the $x$ axis, therefore $f$ is not continuous.

Two questions:

1. Is this proof acceptable/correct?
2. I think this would work for any neighborhood of $0$ on the $y$ axis; is this due to the fact that the discontinuity in the $\epsilon-\delta$ sense is 'at $0$'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The idea of the proof is fine, but you some small mistakes, note that 
   $$ f^{-1}\bigl((-1,1)\bigr) = \color{red}{(-\infty,} 0] \cup {\color{red}(}1,\infty) $$
   which is also not an open set.
2. No, this would not work for any neighbourhood, due to the fact that $f$ continuous at $0$ means 
   $$ \forall U: \bigl(U \text{ open neighbourhood of $0$}\bigr) \to \bigl(f^{-1}(U) \text{ open}\bigr) $$
   hence $f$ is not continuous iff 
   $$ \exists U : \bigl(U \text{ open neighbourhood of $0$}\bigr) \land \bigl(f^{-1}(U) \text{ not open}\bigr) $$

Comment: Thank you. I agree in general that we only need to find one bad neighborhood, but in this case, aren't all neighborhoods of $0$ bad? $$f^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon) = (-\infty,0] \cup \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon},\infty\right)$$ ?

Comment: No. $\mathbf R$ for example, is not.